# Sculpting isn't working ONLY on parts of the mesh (screenshots included)

Tags: modeling, sculpting

This model is in fact made out many parts, each modeled in different technique, Build tool, spin tool, mesh deform on a curve lastly joining all together and filling and bridging the gapes.
Now I need to refine some parts using sculpt tools, but I found out that it's not working on the upper part of the bottle, right under the neck, after trying different modes and workspaces it turned out that this part is sometimes missing (shown in 2nd image).
Also in sculpting workspace the model is multicolored.
I know I may have messed a lot while modeling but now what is the solution.

Normal look:

[image]

turning on sculp mode in Modeling Workspace:

[image]

Sculpting workspace:

[image]

Comment: “Multicolor(s?)” are the face sets I believe

Comment: Yeah this helped, Thanks Mysticreator, I've initialized the face sets and now it all one color and the problem is solved